# how can I create a constraint using two fields

Tags: neo4j

how can I create a constraint using two fields. for example.

**CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (m:BBG_Security_DATA) ASSERT m.ISIN, m.CUSIP IS UNIQUE;**

When I am executing the above cypher statement it is giving an error message.

Thanks,
Shafeeque

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times before. For example, see question #2 of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862488/creating-constraint-on-multiple-properties-in-neo4j/41863964#41863964, and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [triggers](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_triggers) from APOC:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :BBG_Security_DATA (ISIN);

CREATE INDEX ON :BBG_Security_DATA (CUSIP);

CALL apoc.trigger.add(':BBG_Security_DATA (ISIN,CUSIP) IS UNIQUE', '
    UNWIND {createdNodes} AS n 
    WITH n 
         WHERE ALL(l in ["BBG_Security_DATA"] WHERE l in LABELS(n)) AND 
               ALL(k in ["ISIN", "CUSIP"] WHERE k in keys(n))
    MATCH (t:BBG_Security_DATA) 
          WHERE t<>n AND
                ALL(k in ["ISIN", "CUSIP"] WHERE t[k] = n[k])
    DETACH DELETE n
', {phase:'before'});
```

Comment: Very neat, hadn't looked much at apoc triggers. Doesn't look like you'll get a warning if you violate this, though, the violating nodes will just be deleted?

Comment: There is an error message: `Transaction id is not assigned yet. It will be assigned during transaction commit.`

Answer (score 0):

This currently isn't supported by Neo4j. You may be able to code your own extension (likely using a [TransactionEventHandler](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html)) to enforce this kind of behavior, though.